# Pass data back to parent file from a ajax loaded file without using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

In **INDEX.PHP** I open a Boostrap dialog which loads via ajax **BACKUPS.PHP**

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_NORMAL,
    title: 'Backups',
    closable: true,
    message: $('<div></div>').load('backups.php'),
        buttons: [{
            id: 'download_backups',
            label: 'Download selected',
            action: function(dialogItself){
            $.ajax({
                url : 'downloadbackup.php?q=download',                                              
                type: 'POST',
                success : function(data){

                }
            });

            dialogItself.close();
         }]
});
```

**BACKUPS.PHP** renders a list of files that the user can select by checking the relative checkboxes. The values of the checked checkboxes are correctly stored in the array `selected_db_chk` using jQuery:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {

    selected_db_chk = [];

    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
        filename = $(this).val();

        if(selected_db_chk.indexOf(filename) === -1) {  // If not exists...
            selected_db_chk.push(filename);
        }
    });
 });
```

The goal is to pass the array `selected_db_chk` to INDEX.PHP so that it can be then passed to **DOWNLOADBACKUP.PHP** to download the selected files.

My question is how can I pass `selected_db_chk` back to INDEX.PHP using Javascript **NOT PHP**? I thought that if it was declared in INDEX.PHP it would be globally defined:

```
var selected_db_chk;
```

and accessible from other files, but if I try this way when I call it in BACKUPS.php I get `selected_db_chk` is `undefined`.

Comment: It depends where you declare `selected_db_chk`. The botch solution here is to use `window["selected_db_chk"] = []` and use it as `window["selected_db_chk"].push(filename)`, assuming this is all in the same page and there's no reloading done.

Comment: Basically where you'd normally initialise it. I think here you initialise it every time in the `.on(change` function. However you should also check if it is set because you might try to read it when there was no change event triggered in which case you might need to send an empty array.

Comment: Ok, got it and it worked! I declared `window.selected_db_chk = []` in index.php, fill it in backups.php `window.selected_db_chk.push(filename)` and read its content in index.php `console.log(window.selected_db_chk)`.